# How to use correctly satisfies operator (typescript) in async functions responses

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I created a type to represent the response of Signatures requests (for saving written signatures of users) with a Union type because, in POST's requests, the response returns only one Signature, but for GET's, the requests return a array of Signatures:

```js
// SignatureDocument
export interface SignatureDocument {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  file: string;
  hash: string;
  status: number;
  deal_id: number;
}

// Type for response of requests
export interface SignatureDocumentResponse {
  data: SignatureDocument | SignatureDocument[];
  message: string;
  success: boolean;
}
```

But the post that I make with mutation (React Query) returns an error:

```js
      const {
        data: {
          data: { id: signatureDocumentId },
        },
      } = await createSignatureDocumentMutation.mutateAsync({
        name: personFactory.name,
        deal_id: deal.id,
        proposal_id: chosenProposal!.id,
      });
```

The `id` return the next error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'SignatureDocument | SignatureDocument[]'.ts(2339)

How can i use satisfies operator to fix the type issue?

I still don't understand how can I use it, but I know that I need it.

Comment: You can't use `satisfies` to fix this issue, you've got to either create better types - i.e. does your mutation return an array of documents only if you pass in an array, and if you pass in a single object will it return a single document? - or you've just got to narrow the type by checking to see if it's an array first

Comment: I didn't understand your question. But depending on the return type (if is a listing - get or create - post request), the response will bring an array or only one document. So, is the best way to check the return value before adding a type?

Comment: You can leave everything is as, typescript does it's own narrowing so I imagine if you just use an `if(Array.isArray(response))` then typescript will infer the if and the else part.

Comment: Ideally, you should have a more explicit API type and/or response. For example, create a hook that you know will only ever return a single document (no array). Alternatively, you can do a transformation in your hook so that even if the API returns a single document, you convert it into an array inside your mutation hook. The type that allows for a return type of an array or a single document is a little smelly (IMO), but it's also not a show-stopper

Comment: I can see. Thanks, bro <3